# Can't open existing Jupyter notebook or create new notebook in JupyterLab in new environment

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-lab

Today I created a new environment in Anaconda, running Python 3.8.13 and JupyterLab 3.3.2. When I launch JupyterLab, I cannot open my existing notebooks.

The error is:
Unreadable Notebook:
C:\Users...Notebook.ipynb
TypeError("**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_validation_error'")

If I try to create a new notebook, I get an error:
Unexpected error while saving file: [filepath]/Untitled.ipynb
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:

If I switch into any of my existing environments, there are no issues.

I have experimented with installing older versions of JupyterLab but it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Have you tried running the notebook in the base environment?

`conda deactivate myenv` followed by 
`jupyter lab`